# How can i copy the content of a directory into a text file?

Tags: command-line

Let me be clear, what I just want to do is to copy the content of the directory (as if it just were a normal text) into a text file. Is there a command I can use to do that? (a variant of cp maybe?) Or is ctrl+c the only solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if you want what's in a directory (ie. pipe the directory into the file using `ls`), or contents of the file (if so pipe the contents using `cat`).. but you've not provied your OS & release either; thus no clue as to if the directory is *confined* etc.

Comment: Can you expand on your solution using ctrl+c? I do not know this solution.

Comment: @guiverc this "Or is ctrl+c the only solution?" means he is talking about `ls`

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to use the very useful `tree` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/tree) and command. Install it with `sudo apt-get install tree` . See `man tree` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/tree.1.html) for usage instructions.

Example output is below:

> ```
> $ tree /etc/apt/
> /etc/apt/
> ├── apt.conf.d
> │   ├── 01autoremove
> │   ├── 01autoremove-kernels
> │   ├── 01-vendor-ubuntu
> │   ├── 10periodic
> │   ├── 15update-stamp
> │   ├── 20archive
> │   ├── 20auto-upgrades
> │   ├── 20dbus
> │   ├── 20packagekit
> │   ├── 20snapd.conf
> │   ├── 50unattended-upgrades
> │   ├── 70debconf
> │   ├── 99proxy
> │   ├── 99update-notifier
> │   ├── docker-autoremove-suggests
> │   ├── docker-clean
> │   ├── docker-gzip-indexes
> │   └── docker-no-languages
> ├── auth.conf.d
> ├── preferences.d
> ├── sources.list
> ├── sources.list.d
> └── trusted.gpg.d
>    ├── ubuntu-keyring-2012-archive.gpg
>    ├── ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
>    └── ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg
>
> 5 directories, 22 files
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If you pipe the results to a file what was shown in the terminal window will be inside that file. Example:

```
ls -ltr
```

shows a list of files in a directory then ...

```
ls -lrt > listing.log
```

then listing.log will have the same inside the file,

Answer (score 0):

Your question is less detailed and it is kinda hard to understand what you're actually trying to say or help us you with.

In this case i'm assuming you're trying to get all of the file/contents/folder names into a txt file.

To do that you just have to list them and copy the list into a text file. Command for that is `ls > output.txt` using only `ls` will result in having some extra details about the file such as Permissions, Link count, Owner, Group, File size, Last modified date, File name.

To save only the filenames you just have to use `-1a` after the command `ls`. So if you want only the file names just use this command instead `ls -1a > output.txt`